# Is it possible to queue a handler from within an ansible module?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm developing an ansible module inside a role (that is the module lives in the `library` directory of the role). I was wondering if **it's possible to queue a handler from within a module?**

Here's an example of what I'd like to do, but without using the `notify` bit on the task.

```
- name: build and install my application
  custom_module:
    path=/opt/web_app
  notify:
    - restart web server
```

Ideally I'd like to have the `custom_module` somehow queue to handler, so that the usage would look like this:

```
- name: build and install my application
  custom_module:
    path=/opt/web_app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this sort of thing isn't possible.  Modules are, in effect, standalone applications that Ansible copies to a remote host, executes with the provided parameters, then interprets the exit value & output before proceeding on to the next module.  As a module runs on a remote host it has no knowledge of the Ansible process that's running on the master node, so it has no way to hook back to it.  Using the `notify` property in your playbook is the proper way of invoking a handler.  Why would you want to try to do this some other way?

Comment: I suppose you are correct. I'm still trying to figure out a good way to make a dynamic play, That is, build an application and notify some build tool to update its information (in this case`` rbenv rehash``). I thought making the module part of the role, would help with module dependencies and common handler tasks that can be run at the very end. Additionally, I thought this would then prevent all tasks using this module from doing boilerplate dependency tasks as well as notification lines.